# response.sendRedirect is not working in Servlet Filter

Tags: servlets

The following filter is in my `prj2`. From that `prj2` I am checking if the session is not there I want to redirect to the login page of `prj1` which has the url `/prj1/sessionexpiry`. In the following scenario it is not redirecting to the login page and not throwing any exception.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)    
throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpSession session = hreq.getSession(false);

    if (session == null) {
        hsr.sendRedirect("/prj1/sessionexpiry");
        return;
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Remove `return` statement

Comment: After removing return statement also it is not working

Comment: What happened?If any exception or error occur please post.

Comment: No , it is not throwing any exception. It is simply not redirecting, Note : that sessionexpiry is in different application

Comment: Do you see anything on your web-server's logs?

Comment: Are you sure you're not already having a session? Try setting the if-condition to "if (true)" just to verify. It should work according to the documentation, and the servletcontainer should return a 302. Also make sure that you don't have any filters that changes the response.

Answer (score 0):

Did you invalidate the session in a logout servlet or somewhere else? Otherwise, the session will never be null.

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Use this to invalidate the session, then the next time you check whether the session is valid or not, it'll be getting null value.